# Why is my combo box only showing one value when populated by SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

I am using a tpl system with smarty, when I try to make a combo box have multiple selections I only get the option to choose one even though there are more than one values in the query.

Overview2.php:

```
 $smarty->assign("MYTEAM", $team->myteam);
 $smarty->assign("MYTEAMID", $team->myteamid);
 $overview2_tpl = $smarty->fetch("overview2.tpl");
 $smarty->assign("CONTENT", $overview2_tpl);
```

Overview2.tpl:

```
<select name="HScorer1" style="width: 20%;">
<option value ="{$MYTEAMID}" >{$MYTEAM}</option>
</select>
```

class.team.php:

```
var $myteam;
var $myteamid;

$test=$_SESSION['tid'];

function team_class($id, $league){
global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM l1_player where team_id='$test'";
    $mytmp = $db->query_first($sql);
            $this->myteam = $mytmp['player_2name'];
            $this->myteamid = $mytmp['player_id'];
}
```

The table contains multiple rows where team_id=$test with player_2name and player_id
but in the option/combo box it only shows one name, anyway i can make it so all the values show?

Comment: Have you checked the source to make sure you don't have surprises there? (Invalid HTML, unclosed tags, etc)

Comment: I have checked the source i cant see anything wrong because one Row shows in the combo box but the rest dont

Comment: I don't see any looping. You have to loop through a resultset to fill multiple options. Besides that you have strange variable names. In `$this->myTeam` you store a playername and in `$this->myteamid` a **player** id (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a huge SMARTY expert, but it would make sense if `$db->query_first` only returned the first row of the resultset. You're probably looking for a different method.

Comment: @user1626410: As I said, I'm no SMARTY expert. Consult the SMARTY documentation. I'm sure that will help you.